# How to Read or Capture particular parameters from .ipa package

Tags: linux, shell

I have a IOS package (.ipa format)
I would need few parameters from the files info.plist, IntuneMamresource.bundle which are inside the .ipa package

Example :
BundleId:
Bundleversion;

How to capture the above mentioned parameter and its values using Linux shell scripting

TR

we had done the same kind of operation for apk file using powershell with the help of buildtool (aapt.exe)

Comment: Can you post any attempts you've made to solve this?

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# awk '{gsub(/["]/,""); if ($1 = "") {print $0}}' file.txt
[root@localhost ~]# awk '{gsub(/["]/,""); {print $0}}' file.txt
BuildID = com.bhp.fieri.ipa
Buildversion = 10101010
Realeaseversion = 30

i can get it using using awk command but i am expecting above mentioned way? reading these values from ipa package itself instead directly using with file itself